# Is putting lime juice up your nose on a queue-tip safe/effective to relieve sinus pressure?

Tags: home-remedies

I read several places on the internet that said that snorting juice from a fresh lime by putting it on a queue-tip and putting it up your nose could clear up sinus pressure.

Is this safe?  I mean I'm sure it's not something you want to over do.

Comment: In general, any medical procedure that is not prescribed and performed by a health care professional has to be regarded as unsafe. Basically, in medicine everything is assumed to be unsafe until it is proven to be safe. You can consider what the potential problems with this procedure would be that would likely be looked at first before it could ever become accepted practice. E.g. you can consider what would happen if lime juice accidentally enters your lungs, you could look into the risk of [aspiration pneumonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspiration_pneumonia).

Comment: @Countiblis Please submit the above, as an answer ;) (include something about nasal bleeding too - blood vessels rupture due to drying + irritation in the dermis)

Answer (score 2):

In general, any medical procedure that is not prescribed and performed by a health care professional has to be regarded as unsafe. Basically, in medicine everything is assumed to be unsafe until it is proven to be safe. You can consider what the potential problems with this procedure would be that would likely be looked at first before it could ever become accepted practice. E.g. you can consider what would happen if lime juice accidentally enters your lungs, you could look into the risk of [aspiration pneumonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspiration_pneumonia) or nasal bleeding due to irritation as mentioned by user19679 in the comments.

Since there may be other adverse health effects that a priori are hard to identify, the only way to know that a proposed treatment is safe and effective is to do clinical trials and publish the results in a scientific journal. This is the start of the process in which the proposed treatment can be evaluated in scientifically rigorous way.

At the end of the process there will have been independent groups repeating such trials, review papers will have been published that have looked at all the results of this particular treatment and compared the results to other treatments. If the treatment has been found to be a viable treatment that can be used under certain circumstances, then there will be been guidelines for doctors about using this treatment that are based on such review articles.